# Return variable from PHP after AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've read countless examples but I just can't get the following to work.  I want to submit a form, process it on the server side then decide which php script to load into a div (dynamic loading I can do).

The head:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url, // passed with onclick
  data: $("#" + formName).serialize(), 
  success: function(data) {     
    // Some JSON? to go here to store variable returned from PHP ($thisVariable)        
  }
});
return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
```

The php:

```
// Process the request (add to database e.g.) 
$thisVariable back to ajax
```

Comment: `echo "name-of-the-script.php"`

Comment: `then decide which php script to load into a div.` so in php so like `echo "abc.php"` and in ajax  `success: function(data){  $('div id or class').load('base path of the file/'+data);}`

Comment: use json_decode php fun. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Sorry Mike I should have been clearer I wish to load the script based on a variable passed back from php e.g. add data to a database obtain the id and pass the id along with a script back to in the success function and from there load a div using jquery.

Comment: Alive to Die, still a little lost on how to obtain the $thisVariable once I have a successive submit.

Comment: Tareq I did stumble across that page and tried to put it into place but I kept receiving 'underfined' I wasn't sure if I need to specify a dataType within the ajax call?

Comment: I've tried a few more combinations but I can't seem to get from the php script. does anyone have an example they care to share?

Comment: The PHP script should do `echo $thisVariable;`. The contents of the variable will be in `data` in the jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar clearly not but I do now lol seriously thanks.  I've added echo $thisVariable at the end of my php script.  How do I access the variable upon a successful submit?

Comment: It's in the `data` variable in the Javascript.